# Increase the size of variable-size points in ggplot2 scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a scatter plot where each point has a different size corresponding to the number of observations. Below is the example of code and the image output:

```
rm(list = ls())

require(ggplot2)

mydf <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3),
                   y = c(1, 2, 3),
                   count = c(10, 20, 30))

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(aes(size = count))
ggsave(file = '2013-11-25.png', height = 5, width = 5)
```

[image]

This is quite nice, but is there a way to increase the sizes of all of the points? In particular, as it currently is, the point for "10" is too small and thus very hard to see.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use:

`<your ggplot code> + scale_size_continuous(range = c(minSize, maxSize))`

where `minSize` is your minimum point size and `maxSize` is your maximum point size.

Example:

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = count)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 7))
```